# Unable to select element by id

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written a code to select a element by id but it is not getting select. I think id is changing every time.

Code I have written

```
Select Employmenttype = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ApplicantCurrentEmploymentAndIncomes_9341d691-b0c9-4d78-aa32-6b68150c42c9__EmploymentType")));     
Employmenttype.selectByValue("10");
```

HTML code 1st time

```
<select name="ApplicantCurrentEmploymentAndIncomes[9341d691-b0c9-4d78-aa32-6b68150c42c9].EmploymentType" class="DropDownEmploymentType" id="ApplicantCurrentEmploymentAndIncomes_9341d691-b0c9-4d78-aa32-6b68150c42c9__EmploymentType" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); border-image: none;" jQuery18305642460436448337="196"><option value="" selected="">- Select -</option>
```

Id changed on 2nd time

```
<select name="ApplicantCurrentEmploymentAndIncomes[48770411-31e6-4f7f-bff6-08e9ed853194].EmploymentType" class="DropDownEmploymentType" id="ApplicantCurrentEmploymentAndIncomes_48770411-31e6-4f7f-bff6-08e9ed853194__EmploymentType" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); border-image: none;" jQuery18305642460436448337="196"><option value="" selected="">- Select -</option>
```

Can anyone suggest me in this case how I can select element?

Answer (score 2):

You have a dynamic id. You should locate your element by using xpath, so the following code should do the trick:

```
Select Employmenttype = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[contains(@id,ApplicantCurrentEmploymentAndIncomes)]")));     
Employmenttype.selectByValue("10");
```

This way, you're "telling" the driver to locate a `Select` tag node in your html whose `id` contains that particular text.

EDIT: Adding this here for visibility.
Xpath is an extremely powerful tool if used to it's full potential. You can check more examples here: w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp

Comment: I tried your code it is working fine. Can you please tell me how to use xpath similar way as above to send text in text field. I tried `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,EmploymentStartDate)]")).sendKeys(EmpDate);` but it is not working. actually for this employment page id is changing dynamically for all elements. can you please help?

Comment: For the id part, you should check what remains stable (e.g. in your case I'm thinking that it's `EmploymentStartDate`). However, the name of your id, leads me to think that that one is an `input` of date type field, so maybe it's opening a calendar to select the date and the UI is not allowing you to directly input a value, or the value is not in the correct format.